# Javascript showcase website

Tags: javascript

I would like to present some Javascript examples in a Wordpress blog. Since Wordpress doesn't allow me to embed Javascript in blog posts, I am restricted to only present the code.
Is there a website where I can showcase some Javascript examples so that at least I can link to an external html file that contains my javascript code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a great website for testing/demonstrating JS snippets. You'll see it used a lot on StackOverflow (in questions to demonstrate problems and in answers to demonstrate working solutions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would work. It would also make your examples easily editable.